# I have a problem with RTL in special part of my bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css

I am trying to RTL "More filter" checkboxes in the URL below (at the bottom of its sidebar area): 
http://www.vasterad.com/themes/listeo_latest/listings-list-with-sidebar.html
Can anyone know how I can do this?

I try inserting these properties:

```
 Direction: rtl;
```

or

```
 Float: right;
```

or even

```
 text-align: right;
```

none of them can RTL the square checkboxes, only text label RTL.
The square checkbox inserted by ::before selector. I also try to replace it by ::after selector. 
not working again.
It know it might be a simple but actually i could not realize up to know. 
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/b7pm2yws/3/), but it works as expected, at least if you expect the checkbox to be to the right of the text. By the way, I looked at your link, but I don't see any checkboxes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the attribut `left: 0;` for `.checkboxes label:before` to `right: 0;` in the file style.css :

```
.checkboxes label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; //***************change here************//
    top: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all .25s;
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, How about dropdown arrow icon? I change properties right, float etc... but not working, even I change position to absolute and change right and left settings but not working again,

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you have to check the version of jquery and the bootstrap as it is in the example. It may not working in the old version:

```css
.pagination {
    margin: 9px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
 <div class="pagination-container margin-top-20 margin-bottom-40">
 
<nav class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current-page">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="sl sl-icon-arrow-right"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
   </div>
```